# Creating a head-bar

Tags: css, html

Good evening. I keep going on with my game project, but I am stuck at the design process. This time, I would like to ask you something I hope you can help me with. For my webpage, I need a black head-bar just like that used on [**www.google.com**](http://www.google.com). I don't really know what element it is. Is it a div? Being that the case, I have four questions:

· What CSS properties do you think it has? I would like to create one but don't know where to start from.

· How is it possible to divide it into different parts (e.g. Images, Maps, Play, Youtube, News, ...).

. How is it possible to keep it fixed at the top of the browser? (e.g. no distance between the black head-bar and the address bar).

· How can I make it interactive? (e.g. whenever the user hovers the mouse over the elements, they change their font color from gray to white?)

Finally: if not a div element, what element it is?

Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you use the browser Developer Tools (usually `F12`) and see?

Comment: Please study some literature or some guide on the internet how to create web pages. There are thousands, if not millions or billions. We are not here to do your research for you. -1.

Comment: `Right click` -> `Inspect Element` ;-)

Comment: @Hidde I've been looking for "some literature or guides", but I only find "Easy-to-do Photoshop Tutorials", and none of them suits my needs. Thats why I posted my question.

Comment: You are asking questions about creating a web page, so look for HTML and CSS tutorials. Believe me, there are many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple...

**CSS**

```
html, body{
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}
#head{
    width:100%;
    background:#111;
    position:fixed;
}
#head a{
    color:#999;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:30px;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
#head a:hover{
    color:#eee;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='head'>
    <a href="#" style="margin-left:10px">Search</a>
    <a href="#">Images</a>
    <a href="#">Maps</a>
    <a href="#">Play</a>
</div>
```

You can remove `style="margin-left:10px"` or change it as you see fit...

Comment: Thanks Steven for having taken the trouble. I would like to ask, is it really necessary to set "margin:0", "padding:0", "border:0" in html and body sets? Thanks!

Comment: It's necessary _if_ you want it to display right up against the edge of the browser. I suggest you try it with and without to see what I mean! But, for the question you asked `no distance between the black head-bar and the address bar` it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

http://css3menu.com/modern-css3-menu-bar.html

http://www.creativeverse.com/40-css3-html5-dropdown-menus/

That should be good to get you started.  In the future use your browser's dev tools and element inspector, or hire a designer.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the dev tools nor the element inspector. I don't have any money either, if I had I would have already hired a professional ! Thanks for the links, they will help me with my task.